# show checked when the option is selected

Tags: html, angular

I have two API, one that returns the list of all permissions and second that returns the list of selected permissions(contains permission Object) now I want to show the list of permissions in checkboxes but if the permission is already selected then show checkmark with it.

***component.ts***

```
getUserPermissions() {
this.permissionService.getUsersPermission().subscribe(permission => {
    this.permission = permission;
 })
}
getAssignedPermissions(uuid: any) {
this.permissionService.getAssignedPermissions(uuid, true).subscribe(res 
 =>{
    this.userPermission = res;
   })
}
```

***component.html***

```
<form  id="permission" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-group">

<div *ngFor="let permission of permission" >
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               value="{{permission.code}}"
               [(ngModel)]="permission.Checked"
               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

              />
        {{permission.code}}
    </label>

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn theme-btn  btn-secondary">SAVE</button>
```

Comment: Can you share stackBiltz

Comment: Actually I am calling the api using apollo client  so I think its difficult

Comment: You can have a dummy data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a method that check if the permission is already assigned

```
<form  id="permission" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-group">

<div *ngFor="let permission of permission" >
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               value="{{permission.code}}"
               [ngModel]="permission.Checked || isassigned(permission)"
               (ngModelChange)="permission.Checked = $event"
               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

              />
        {{permission.code}}
    </label>

</div>
```

```js
isassigned(permission) {
  const p = this.userPermission.find(p => p.code === permission.code)
  return this.userPermission.find(p => p.code === permission.code) ? true: false
}
```

[live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkboxes-configuration)

Comment: Could the one who downvoted this question please be considerate in telling why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by using `async-await` and iterate through permissions to check whether user permission is existing.

```
async getAllPermissions() {
    this.userpermission = await this.permissionService.getUsersPermission().toPromise();
    this.permission = await this.permissionService.getAssignedPermissions(uuid, true).toPromise();

    this.permission.forEach(permission => {
        if (this.userPermission.find(uPermission => uPermission === permission)) {
            permission.Checked = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I just the marked all the selected permissions as checked but how can I use this in html?
<input type="checkbox"
               value="{{permission.code}}"
               [(ngModel)]="permission.Checked"
               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
               [checked] = "your value"
              />

Answer (score -1):

You should just use [] for ngModel

```
<form  id="permission" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-group">

<div *ngFor="let permission of permission" >
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               value="{{permission.code}}"
               [ngModel]="permission.Checked"
               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

              />
        {{permission.code}}
    </label>

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn theme-btn  btn-secondary">SAVE</button>
```